# Print out onto same line with ":" separating variables

Tags: bash

I have the following piece of code and would like to display `HOST` and `RESULT` side by side with a `:` separating them.

```
HOST=`grep pers results.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`
RESULT=`grep cleanup results.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/K/000/' -'s/M/000000/'`
echo ${HOST}${RESULT}
```

Please can anyone assist with the final command to display these, I am just getting all of hosts and then all of results.

Comment: `with a : seperating them` -- Say: `echo "${HOST}:${RESULT}"`

Comment: Sorry I should have explained properly, the greps return more that one result. I get a list of strings for host and a list of ints for result. the returned strings and ints are in the correct order e.g. HOST[0] and RESULT[0] match up. I want to display them side by side.

Comment: Provide your sample data from results.txx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
HOST=( `grep pers results.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }'` ) #keep the output of the command in an array
RESULT=( `grep cleanup results.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed -e 's/K/000/' -'s/M/000000/'` )
for i in "${!HOST[@]}"; do
    echo "${HOST[$i]}:${RESULT[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: You sir are a champion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A version that works without arrays, using an extra file handle to read from 2 sources at at time.

```
while read host; read result <&3; do
    echo "$host:$result"
done < <( grep peers results.txt | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}' ) \
     3< <( grep cleanup results.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's/K/000/' -'s/M/000000/')
```

It's still not quite POSIX, as it requires process substitution. You could instead use explicit fifes. (Also, an attempt to shorten the pipelines that produce the hosts and results. It's probably possible to combine this into a single `awk` command, since you can either do the substitution in `awk`, or pipe to `sed` from within `awk`. But this is all off-topic, so I leave it as an exercise to the reader.)

```
mkfifo hostsrc
mkfifo resultsrc
awk -F: '/peers/ {split($2, a, ' '); print a[1]}' results.txt > hostsrc &
awk -F: '/cleanup/ {split($2, a, ' '); print a[1]}' results.txt | sed -e 's/K/000' -e 's/M/000000/' > resultsrc &

while read host; read result <&3; do
    echo "$host:$result"
done < hostsrc 3< resultsrc
```